# Halting problem in C++

Tags: halting-problem, c++

The halting problem relies on the fluidity of Turing machines. That is, a string can represent a machine.

Can you do the same for C++ on a modern computer?

Let's see my first attempt. Let `bool h(string x, string y)` be the purported function that decides haltingness and always halts. You can easily turn it into a full program.

Now define a self-contradictory function `f`:

```
bool f(string x) {
    if (h(x, x))
        for (;;);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    cout << h(f, f) << endl;
}
```

The problem is that I can't feed the code of `f` into `h` in `main()`.

My second attempt: Prepare 4 files: `h.cpp`, `h.exe`, `f.cpp`, `f.exe`. And suppose the call formats are

```
h.exe filename1 filename2
f.exe filename
```

My problem is that in `f.cpp` I need to call `h.exe`, which in turn has to be part of `f.cpp`.

What's your working scheme?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Proving the halting problem is undecidable by C++ machines, I assume?

Comment: @dkaeae Is turning a C++ program into a Turing machine the only way to prove that this program can't solve the halting problem? I want to do the argument in C++ and hence bypassing the idea of Turing machines altogether. I don't like the idea of Turing machines. Or is it that in C++ this argument is not viable and hence Turing machines are necessary? I want to shoot down the belief that there is no halting problem in C++ programs, i.e., you can decide haltingness for the set of C++ programs. If you believe the set of Turing machines and the set of C++ programs are indeed equal, do it in C++.

Comment: Surely you can feed the code of `f` into `h`. Just write it again as a literal string.

Comment: But also keep in mind, that then you either need to include the source of `h` into that string, or you need to be sure that `h` knows that `"h(x,x)"` means call of `h` itself.

Comment: The key problem is to solve the fluidity problem. It's easy to convert strings to Turing machines and back. But how to do that in C++? That's the main difficulty. I think it's too easy with TMs and conjecture that it's impossible with C++, under my current understanding.

Comment: @dkaeae Turing machines are universal. But is C++ universal? Is this halting problem something C++ can't do?

Comment: @ZiruiWang What do you mean by "universal"? Turing-complete? Is there a particular reason you believe C++ would not be Turing-complete? Virtually *every* programming language is. Almost every example of the ones that aren't were deliberately constructed to not be Turing-complete.

Comment: @dkaeae This halting problem is exactly the counterexample to C++'s Turing-completeness I have in mind. If the completeness theorem is true, this should not be a problem. Please work it out or convince me that it's viable.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz I'm so sorry that I didn't define the requirements of this version of the halting problem properly. That's my first try. I think the second attempt is better. Take that as the problem statement and solve it.

Comment: This is not a counterexample for Turing-completeness at all. The halting problem is undecidable by TMs. C++ not solving the halting problem does not contradict completeness in any way. AFAICT your only problem is figuring out how to pass C++ code to a function, which is just implementation trivia.

Comment: @dkaeae If there is a C++ program deciding whether an arbitrary C++ program halts, then the set of C++ programs is strictly smaller than the set of TMs, and hence C++ is not as powerful as TMs. The failure of the halting argument is certainly a step in that direction. The TM version of the argument might not stop us from solving the C++ version of the halting problem. We should explore this direction, which is not mentioned elsewhere as far as I know.

Comment: "C++ on a modern computer" is irrelevant to the halting problem as it's not Turing-complete.

Comment: >>>"C++ on a modern computer" is irrelevant to the halting problem as it's not Turing-complete.<<< @Raphael that is not true. Every algorithm that can be computed within the amount of RAM available can be encoded as a computable C/C++ function that is Turing equivalent.

Comment: True. However, the _modern computer_ does not have infinite memory so it (together with a programming language, let's call that model of computation PC+C for short) is not equivalent to the computational models of Turing Machines or RAMs used in computability theory. _Technically_ PC+C can be modelled by a finite automaton -- and its halting problem is therefore Turing-decidable (but not necessarily PC+C-decidable).

Comment: All of the modern termination analyzers translate higher level language functions into "symbolic execution graphs" and then analyze the graph to determine termination. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642315000271

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prove that the halting problem for C++ programs can't be decided by a C++ program, just copy the proof of the Halting problem but replace every use of a universal Turing machine with a C++ interpreter/compiler that's written in C++.

Comment: Yes, the translation is not as trivial as advertised in textbooks.

Comment: @ZiruiWang There are reasons textbooks stick to stripped-down formal models of computation; you found one.  Real-world computation requires different trade-offs in language/model design.

Answer (score 2):

The halting problem states that there is no $h$ function that works on every input. You are missing that you need to supply a concrete implementation of a function $h$ (which is as hard as writing a compiler), and prove that it works on any input function. The latter is an impossible task, as you should feed $h$ with all valid programs.

The proof of the halting problem is not constructive, it just shows the impossibility.

Comment: The proof of undecidability of the halting problem _is_ constructive.

Comment: "The problem is that I can't feed the code of f into h in main().
What's your working scheme?" Your answer does not address the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is that I can't feed the code of f into h in main().

This problem is solved by invoking h with the machine address of f.

**Translated to C for the x86utm operating system**

```
00 typedef int (*ptr)();
01 int h(ptr x, ptr y)
02
03 int f(ptr x) {
04   if (h(x, x))
05     for (;;);
06   return 1;
07 }
08
09 int main() 
10 {  
11  Output("Input_Halts = ", h(f, f));
12 }
```

When h is a simulating termination analyzer based on an
x86 emulator within the x86utm operating system this is
the execution trace of the above code:

**Line 11:** main() calls h(f,f) that simulates f(f)

**keeps repeating:** 
**Line 04:** simulated f(f) calls simulated h(f,f) that simulates f(f) ...

**Simulation invariant:** 
f correctly simulated by h never reaches its own Line 06.

This enables h to correctly report that (its input) f correctly simulated by h never halts.
The above is fully operational code within the x86utm operating system